# Is $T(U) \otimes T(V) \cong T(U \oplus V)$?

Tags: tensor-products

I Know that $S(U) \otimes S(V) \cong S(U \oplus V)$, but is it also true for tensor algebras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The tensor algebra functor, as a functor to algebras, is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from algebras to vector spaces. Consequently it preserves all colimits, and in particular it sends coproducts (direct sums) of vector spaces to coproducts of algebras. But the coproduct in algebras is the free product, which is much more complicated than the tensor product of algebras.

Comment: Can you think of an example that shows the isomorphism isn't true?

Comment: @Joe: the free product of two algebras is almost never equal to their tensor product; every pair of nonzero $U, V$ is a counterexample. To be very explicit, you can take $\dim U = \dim V = 1$, in which case the LHS is a polynomial algebra $k[x, y]$ in two variables but the RHS is a free algebra $k \langle x, y \rangle$ in two variables.